# Trying to make an object rotate towards the mouse in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've been trying to use the atan2 function to rotate an object (triangle) towards the mouse, but it can't seem to rotate correctly in one direction. any ideas?

```
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        double ydistance = p.y-triangle.getTranslateY();
        double xdistance = p.x-triangle.getTranslateX();
        double angle5 = Math.toDegrees(atan2(xdistance, ydistance));
        triangle.setRotate(angle5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inverted the x and y

atan2 is defined as atan2(y, x) not atan2(x, y), as you might expect.

refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-math-atan2-java/

> It is the counterclockwise angle, measured in radian, between the
>   positive X-axis, and the point (x, y).

also note that radian 0 begins from positive X-Axis,Y=0 (East)

[image]

Comment: In image coordinates the y axis is also inverted, so your diagram is wrong in that regard and it's clockwise, not counter-clockwise on the screen.